# Two output files share the same path but have different contents, vite error

Tags: three.js, vite

Help, I'm following a youtube tutorial on how to build a website with three.js but I'm stuck. I started getting this error message after I tried to import orbit controls. I'm using vite as you can see, it's been showing a white screen or an error message the same as in the terminal.

I'm new to using three.js and pretty new to programming in general so any help would be greatly appreciated.

22:39:53 [vite] error while updating dependencies:
Error: Build failed with 1 error:
error: Two output files share the same path but have different contents: node_modules/.vite/deps_temp/three.js
at failureErrorWithLog (/Users/lo/Documents/3d_website_tut/index_3d_website/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1566:15)
at /Users/lo/Documents/3d_website_tut/index_3d_website/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1024:28
at runOnEndCallbacks (/Users/lo/Documents/3d_website_tut/index_3d_website/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1438:61)
at buildResponseToResult (/Users/lo/Documents/3d_website_tut/index_3d_website/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1022:7)
at /Users/lo/Documents/3d_website_tut/index_3d_website/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1134:14
at responseCallbacks. (/Users/lo/Documents/3d_website_tut/index_3d_website/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:671:9)
at handleIncomingPacket (/Users/lo/Documents/3d_website_tut/index_3d_website/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:726:9)
at Socket.readFromStdout (/Users/lo/Documents/3d_website_tut/index_3d_website/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:647:7)
at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)

Answer (score 0):

I think this was a temporary bug with Vite, it is working after ignoring it for a day